# Browser Fullscreen without Message on Keydown

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-applications, browser, fullscreen

I implemented firefox's fullscreen functionality in my [new webapp](http://openwords.org). When entering the fullscreen firefox shows a message saying the user how to cancel fullscreen. You can see this behaviour on every [youtube](http://youtube.com) video.

This message also appears every time the user *presses any key* on the keyboard.

Because my webapp is about writing down words the message shows up very often. This way it hides some user interface of my webapp and irritates the user.

How can I prevent firefox from showing this message because of a keydown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new fullscreen api of new Firefox releases behaves exactly in the way I was looking for. So the question sorted itself out.